# Setting a .DOC file to open in Web Layout

Tags: microsoft-word, html

I have a .doc file (actually it's an html file, which I renamed .doc, so that Word will open it). Word defaults to open it in print layout. However, I want it to open in Web layout. It has to be something in this file (not in my Word settings), so that I'll be able to send this file to friends, and it'll always open in Web layout. How is it possible, considering that it's really an .html file?

Comment: Word can open .html files anyway, so why did you change the extension to .doc, thereby confusing everything?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need both sides to open a HTML file in Word?

Comment: I want Word to be the default program for this file (so thatdouble-click will open it, and not the browser). And it looks much better in Web Presentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Sorry, but your answer is: this cannot be done.

There is no setting inside a Word document for the viewing mode in which in must open. The only way this could be done would be with macros in the document, which probably will not be allowed by the recipient.

The comments to your question point out other considerations. Word will seldom be the default program for opening .html files.

If you truly want the .html document opened in Word in web view, why not simply include that information with the link to it or at the top of the document.

Comment: There should be a way to do it. When I open a file in Word, in Print layout, and save it as html, its <head> section contains this: <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Print</w:View>
  Interestingly, this attribute doesn't seem to be honored.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such method. Word is a horrible html editor and that code

Answer (score 0):

How about a Macro?

```vb
Sub AutoExec()
Application.OnTime When:=DateAdd("s", 1, Now), Name:="SetWebView"enter
End Sub

Sub SetWebView()
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer works? Also a disclaimer for the dangers of macros would be helpful, as this seems to be a newbie question.